# Web Scraping multiple pages of a web site?

Tags: python, web-scraping

My problem is i am trying to scrape data form a web page with multiple web pages of witch each is a separate blog post. But the current code only scrapes the data form the url that i have set as  variable source.

```
source = requests.get('https://www.trenerklemen.si/objave/').text.
```

I would like to scrape text from other url but one part is dynamic and i have no idea how to access it

```
source = requests.get('https://www.trenerklemen.si/?????/').text
```

How would i get the **????** part if it changes. Thanks for the answers.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.trenerklemen.si/objave/').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

article = soup.find('article')

headline = article.h2.text

print(headline)

summary = article.find('div', class_='post-content').p.text

print(summary)
video = article.find('iframe', class_ ='youtube-player')['src']

video_id = video.split('/')[4]
video_id = video_id.split('?')[0]

yt_link = f'https://youtube.com/watch?v={video_id}'

print(yt_link)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't read the language that the website is in so I'm trying to understand your goal. Are you trying to go through all of the pages in the header menu and check them all for articles? In other words check pages "http://trenerklemen.si/objav/", "https://www.trenerklemen.si/treningi-in-cenik/", etc?

Comment: I know i should not use a page with foreign language to avoid confusion. What i am trying to do is to get the content from all the blog posts that are listed under "https://www.trenerklemen.si/objave/". Each of them has "read more" button. So i would like to access them all.

Answer (score 0):

Websites usually use sitemaps for search engines to be able to crawl the content. You can use the sitemap as a source of your links to **scrape**.

Sitemap for your website: https://www.trenerklemen.si/post-sitemap.xml

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

mainLink = "https://www.trenerklemen.si"

ALL_links = ["https://www.trenerklemen.si/objave/"]

counter = 0
while(counter < len(ALL_links)):
    source = requests.get(ALL_links[counter]).text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

    for link in soup.findAll('a'):
        LinkNow = str(link.get('href'))
        if(len(LinkNow) > 0):
            if(LinkNow not in ALL_links):
                if(LinkNow[0] == '/'):
                    ALL_links.append("https://www."+mainLink+LinkNow)
                if(mainLink in LinkNow):
                    ALL_links.append(LinkNow)
    try:
        article = soup.find('article')

        headline = article.h2.text

        print(headline)

        summary = article.find('div', class_='post-content').p.text

        print(summary)
        video = article.find('iframe', class_ ='youtube-player')['src']

        video_id = video.split('/')[4]
        video_id = video_id.split('?')[0]

        yt_link = f'https://youtube.com/watch?v={video_id}'

        print(yt_link)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error: "+str(e))
    counter += 1
```